# Magento - how to Locate physically a specific class in Magento 1.7.2

Tags: php, function, class, magento

Does anybody know how can I locate the physical path of a class in Magento?

For example this class: **Idev_OneStepCheckout_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Comment**

Seems that it follows a pattern of folders - but its not always the case.

**Can you give me an idea how to locate this class ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento names classes the way Zend Framework does. Replace the undescore with a slash and get the name of the file and ad `.php` at the end. So in your case `Idev_OneStepCheckout_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Comment` should be located in the file
`Idev/OneStepCheckout/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View/Comment.php`. This path is relative to a codepool. Magento has 3 such codepools all located in `app/code/`.

1. `core` - Unless the class name starts with `Mage` or `Enterprise`
   for EE version you shouldn't look here
2. `community` - this hold the community modules
3. `local` - this holds local extensions (but some community extensions can also be placed here).

So you should look in `local` or `community` folder for your class. Look for them in that order (first `local` then `community`) because in special cases the file can be in both of them but the one in `local` has priority. (This rarely happens).

An other place the class can be is the `lib` folder (but this is not the case for you). In there there are core classes like `Zend_*` or `Varien_*` and a few others.